# Packets: How are they affected with DNS configurations?

Tags: dns

Sorry if this is a very basic question. I'm trying to learn as much as I can about how packets are sent across the different layers on Protocol Stack.

One confusion I have is with DNS protocol. When I set my machine's DNS server from default to say 8.8.8.8 . How are the packets, affected? Do they retain DNS server IP in the header? Or my understanding is wrong about packets/DNS?

Thank you

Comment: Can you please explain further what exactly your understanding of DNS is? It seems to be incorrect but it would be good to know more about how you think it works.

Comment: Welcome to Network Engineering.  Be sure to take the tour to see how this SE works:  https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Data packets are not affected. Packets are *always* sent from one numeric address to another.

The DNS server is queried for the numeric address of a domain name *before* sending a packet. (DNS itself uses network packets for the query, though and those *will* be affected).

If you change your configured DNS server from A to B and then ping www.google.com, your PC (specifically, the OS) will ask B (instead of A) for the numeric address of www.google.com. Once the OS knows the numeric address it will send data packets to whatever address resulted from the query.

> Do they retain DNS server IP in the header? Or my understanding is wrong about packets/DNS?

Your understanding of DNS seems to be wrong. There is no DNS field in the IP header.

Answer (score 1):

IP knows nothing about DNS or names, so packets are not affected by DNS. IP only understands IP addresses, not DNS names. An application will use DNS to resolve a name to an IP address before IP can be used by the application.

As a protocol above OSI Layer 4, questions about DNS are off-topic.